# Javascript automatically closes form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make a table row into a form with a button. I want to put the form closing tag at the end of the table row. But it is always set directly after the form opening tag.

I don't know if it's related to the fact that I remove a form when overwriting cell 0. But I actually did that before.

I also tried to remove the form-closing tag but it remains there.

```
function editRow(sequence){
sequence -= 1;
table = document.getElementById("mainSiteTable");


table.rows[sequence].cells[0].innerHTML = "<input id ='number' name='sequence' type='number' value='" + (sequence+1) + "'>";

row = document.getElementById("trSequence"+(sequence+1));
row.innerHTML = "<form action='mainsite.php?country=<?= $country?>' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" + row.innerHTML;
row.innerHTML.replace("</fom>","");
row.append("</form>");

table.rows[sequence].cells[2].innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='" + table.rows[sequence].cells[2].innerHTML + "'>";
}
```

Comment: The `.innerHTML` isn't just a string. It's a representation of the DOM. Writing to it turns the string into DOM immediately. So, you *cannot write invalid HTML there*. The browser will auto-correct the HTML and you get whatever it thinks its valid next time you read `.innerHTML`. If you write just an opening tag, you'd get a closing one. If you write tags that cannot be nested, in each other, the inner one is probably going to be removed, etc.

Comment: And then what should I take instead of innerhtml?

Comment: Either create the string upfront and only when it's complete do `.innerHTML = completeHTMLString` or build up the elements programatically via `document.createElement()` and similar, then append it directly to the DOM with `row.append(myCompleteForm)`.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I execute, nothing changes. When I look in Firefox in the inspector what has changed everything is displayed correctly, but only grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build the string before you add it into the html.

```js
row = document.getElementById("trSequence"+(sequence+1));

const formString = "<form action='mainsite.php?country=<?= $country?>' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" + row.innerHTML + '</form>

row.innerHTML.replace(formString);
```